# Reading text from stdin (without fopen)

Tags: c, stdin

I'm trying to write some code to read my text file from stdin char by char, line by line, without using `fopen`. I need 42 lines with a maximum of 100 chars.

Help me to get this working and explain to me how it works. Thank you!

```
int main()                                                      
{
char str[100];

fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
fputs(str, stdout);
return 0;}
```

Comment: `while(character != '\n');` Will cause an endless loop (assuming `character` does not have an initial value of `\n`).

Comment: @pzaenger We are not supposed to use this function :-/

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Unfortunately i've got no clue how to make it. Could you please try to explain it to me?

Comment: If you are just echoing the input back to the console, why do you need to store it in the array? To just read `stdin` char-by-char you could use `getchar()`. See the documentation for [`getchar()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar)

Comment: So this is a homework assignment?  Goal is to demonstrate the ability to read characters from stdin, storing them in an array of lines and then print each of those lines?  You really should post the assignment your teacher gave you, along with whatever code you have and an accurate description of your difficulties.

Comment: @jwdonahue Im sorry. Yes, that's a little piece of the task. I've edited the code. Now it works and prints the first line of .txt. I would like to print the whole .txt file. Possibly 2D character array and put it into cycle? Thank you

Comment: Have you learned how do/while, do and for loops work yet?

Comment: Also, please make up your mind whether you want to read the data into a 2D buffer of characters, an array of char pointers, or just print the data to the screen.  You must say these things in your post above, not in the comments.  It would be better if you just copied the problem statement that your teacher gave you, into the post.  That would give us clue what an appropriate answer to your query should look like.  We're not here to write code for you or help you get out of thinking your way through this problem.  We are here to answer your questions and will do so, when you ask coherently.

Comment: @jwdonahue I just want to print the data on the screen. Task is to make a 2D character array and print all those string lines on the screen (from .txt input). I assume while would be the best option.  I need somehow to make a "linecounter".

Comment: We should avoid using do.

Comment: Fixing your homework is not what SO is for.

Comment: @xCute Devil, one more try.  Edit your original question to make it clear, exactly what your assignment is, not what you think you should do.  Read from stdin or read from a text file?  Put the data from the file into a 2D array, or just write it to stdout?

Answer (score 0):

> without using fopen

If `open` is tolerated. Why not use it with `read` ? This solution will allow you to read char by char.

```
int main(void)
{
  int file_descriptor = open("./path", O_RDWR); /* Open with read/write */
  char text_block[10]; // Random size

  read(file_descriptor, text_block, 1); /* This will read 1 characters
  from the file */

  /* Then do what you want with the char readed. */
}
```

Considering this solution, here is a process which will work :

1. Use `stat()` function to **know the size of the file** (read the manual)
2. Use the same process as above but **instead of read 1 char read the size of the file**
3. Each line is separated by **'\n'** exept the last one. Just use this to separate your fully readed file into lines

I guess it's for homework... This code have an error **and won't compile until you found it.** Which mean search the manual on the net and read it.